# Manipulate data before returning observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am pretty new with Angular 2 and the concept of Observables. However what i am trying to achieve should be fairly simple for experienced gurus :)

So:
I have a component in which i have `subscribed` the observable which is coming from a service. For testing purposes, i have been using data Arrays to make my components live. Now that when its done, i want to hook real API calls to my service. Now the problem is that the data that i get from the server needs to be manipulated before its returned to the component. When i manipulate it, i get error such as "cannot read property 'subscribe' of null"

Now basically this error is coming because in my service observable, i send an API request using HTTP.get method and the code doesn't wait for its response to finish. I do get the result from server but that comes after the error in console.

Can anyone please guide me how to request an HTTP call and then manipulate its data before sending it to the component that has the services subscribed?

Here is my component code:

```
getSearchResults(keyword, parentId?, subCatId?) {
    this.subscriptionResults = this.catalogService.getSearchResults(keyword, parentId, subCatId)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.results                = data.results.parts;
                this.numResults             = data.results.totalItemCount;
                this.timeResults            = data.results.processingTimeMS;
                this.categories             = data.categories;
                this.subCategories          = data.subCategories;
                this.brands                 = data.brands;
                this.suppliers              = data.suppliers;
                this.layoutType             = data.layoutType;
                this.allCategories          = data.allCategories;
                this.selCategoryName        = data.selCategoryName;
                this.selSubCategoryName     = data.selSubCategoryName;

                if ( this.debugMode ) {
                    console.log('RESULTS: ', data);
                }
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}
```

And here is my service:

```
// Get data from server
getDataFromServer(URL: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(URL).flatMap(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}


getSearchResults(keyword: string, parentCatId?:number, subCatId?:number): Observable<any> {

    let request = null;
    let result  = null;

    let URL = this.API_URL + '/search?categoryId=' + subCatId + '&format=json';
    request = this.getDataFromServer(URL);

    request.subscribe(
        () => { 
            // Modify result here and send it back 
        },
        error => { console.log('ERROR: ', <any>error); }
    );
```

I want to manipulate the response data before i want to return it. How can i do that?

**-- EDIT --**
If i return a BehaviorSubject:

```
return new BehaviorSubject<any>(request.subscribe(
            res => { return this.processResultData(res, layoutType, keyword, parentCatId, subCatId); },
            err => { console.log('RETURN ERROR: ', <any>err); }
        ));
```

I get subscription object in my component (which is what i dont need). Instead i need the data thats inside of the subscription.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your component is subscribing to the return value from `getSearchResults()` so that function needs to return an Observable. Your `getDataFromServer()` function returns an observable, so what you can do is use `Observable.map()` on that return value. Observable.map() lets you modify the value moving through an observable stream, and return a new observable of the modified value. That new observable is the one your component will want to subscribe to, so that is what should be returned.

In code, it would look like:

```
getSearchResults(keyword: string, parentCatId?:number, subCatId?:number): Observable {

    let request = null;
    let result  = null;

    let URL = this.API_URL + '/search?categoryId=' + subCatId + '&format=json';
    return this.getDataFromServer(URL).map(
        (response) => {

            // Modify response here

            // Return modified response
        }
    ).catch((error) => { console.log('ERROR: ', error); });
}
```

When your component subscribes, it should see the modified response that comes from the `.map()`.

Comment: Thanks! @Alex It does work with `.map` method. The funny thing is i tried it before but for some reason i was getting an `undefined` error. There is however one thing thats not working now. The data i get displays correctly in the same component. However parts of it that i send to other components keep showing 'Loading...' Do i need to trigger some event for them to pick the new values up? (I thought it would be automatic)

Comment: To clarify - I get an object 'categories' which i pass to a child component to display. It doesn't detect the change. I did try to use the `async` pipe but that didn't help either.

Comment: ah - sorry never mind. Turns out the [input] i was sending was being copied to another value in `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook and so the changes were not updated.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the accepted answer, since pipable operators (RxJs v5.5) it should be written as

```
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and then

```
  return this.getDataFromServer(URL).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        // Modify response here
      }),
      catchError(error => console.log('ERROR: ', error))
  );
```