# How to set a value on a filtered Observable

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 9.  I getting a filtered list of objects. I would like to alter the value on the returned object.

I have the following code:

```
  private setFilteredApproverOptions(): void {
    for (const field in this.approvalEditFormGroup.controls) {
      console.log(field);
      this.approvalEditFormGroup.get(field).valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        if (value && typeof value.valueOf() === "string") {
          this.filteredApproverOptions = this._filter(value);
          this.filteredApproverOptions.forEach(person => {console.log(person)});
        }
      });
    }
  }

  private _filter(value: string): Observable<Person[]> {
    const filterValue: string = value.toLowerCase();
    let respApprovalState: Observable<Person[]> = this.getApproverOptions(filterValue);
    respApprovalState.subscribe(approverOptions => {
      return approverOptions.filter(option => (option.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) || option.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)));
    });
    return respApprovalState;
  }

  private getApproverOptions(searchString: string): Observable<Person[]> {
    let companyName: string = this.approvalEdit.companyName;
    let respApprovalState: Observable<Person[]> = this.service.getApprovers(companyName, searchString);

    respApprovalState.subscribe((approverOptions: Person[]) => {
      this.approverOptions = approverOptions as Person[];
      return approverOptions;
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error calling getApprovers service', error);
      return null;
    });

    return respApprovalState;
  }
```

The following line:

```
this.filteredApproverOptions.forEach(person => {console.log(person)});
```

Has this output:

[image]

I would like to set the `x` and `y` values to a hard-coded value (e.g. `1`).

e.g.

```
x: 1, y: 1, personId: 105702...
```

**Question**

How can I set the above `x` and `y` values?

More info:

```
export class Person {
    public constructor(init?: Partial<Person>) {
      Object.assign(this, init);
    }
    x: number;
    y: number;
    personId: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    companyName: string;
    staffCode: string;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add property to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922998/add-property-to-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: It is an `Observable` and not and `array`. So I cannot call `.map` on `this.filteredApproverOptions`.

Comment: If it is an Observable then call pipe(map()) instead.

Comment: Please [edit] the title and body of your question to make it clear you are dealing with `Observables`

Comment: It is still clearly a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619699/manipulate-data-before-returning-observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to map your observable and then your array. Mapping an observable works almost the same way as with an array. Here you go:

```
const mapped = this.filteredApproverOptions.pipe(map(    // obs.pipe(map(...)) is changing each value coming in an observable/subject
    pArr => pArr.map(p => ({...p, x: 1, y: 1}))          // arr.map(...) is changing each value in an array
));
```

Now you could subscribe to it or whatever you want to do with it, like so:

```
mapped.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Reference:

- To map an array

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- To map an observable

  - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map
  - [What does the `map` method mean in RxJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107986/what-does-the-map-method-mean-in-rxjs)

Comment: Compile error: `Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?`

Comment: You need to import map from rxjs operators, like so: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` @Richard